# Unable to generate proxy classes from IRS Web Service URL

Tags: asp.net, irs

I want to write application to consume IRS 1095-C web service with Visual Studio. 
I'm unable to add IRS service URL as "service reference" in Visual Studio to create proxy classes. Do anybody know how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

While Brian is correct in how you add the Service Reference.  For the IRS A2A Project, I would abandon attempting to use the WSDL.  Myself and others have found that it just plain does not work with .NET; because it is quite troublesome if not nigh impossible to get the Service to accept what you're sending.

Answer (score 1):

You need to point directly at the WSDL that you download.  You can't add the service reference directly via the url.